# Tkinter new window declaration

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently while using python tkinters declaration has not been working. What i mean by this is that a for any file where tkinter has not been imported before, simple code such as creating a window is not possible. Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, how is it solved?
Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.
The code is simply supposed to open a window in tkinter. But, when run, no window is displayed.

```
from tkinter import *

def sample():
    window = Tk()

sample()
```

Comment: Please do not down vote. I have been unable to solve this for a while and I'm sure it affects many other users in addition to myself.

Comment: What does "not possible" mean? Why isn't it possible? What does this code do? There's simply not enough information in this question for us to be able to answer it.

Comment: Your code did not call tkinter `mainloop()`, so what do you expect to see?

Comment: @XeEntity Can you clarify the `import tkinter; tkinter.Tk()` versus `from tkinter import *; Tk()` situation? Someone edited your question and they might have accidentally solved the problem, which makes things difficult to understand.

Comment: @acw1668 When I am to run this code on other systems main loop is unneeded.

Comment: @AMC with `from tkinter import *` all that needs to be written is `Tk()` not `tkinter.Tk()`

Comment: @Bryan Oakley The question has been updated with relevant information. When I mention it **not working** I mean that the code has no effect and the expected outcome is not achieved. Yet, this does work on other systems.

Comment: @XeEntity I know, I’m asking about what your actual program looks like.

Comment: @AMC That is the whole program, I'm not allowed to ask about specific work. My project is somewhat large and I occasionally export some code to an external file for testing purposes, it's just that recently that part has not been working. The file used to test whether this module worked was blank and that was the only code running. I was just wondering if without `mainloop()` and `.update()`. Given this is what I could do prior to this recent period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's so interesting.

You have to use tkinter.Tk() instead of Tk().

Thanks

Comment: It looks like this may be the case unless "from tkinter import *" was used.

Comment: It's my typing mistakes. Yeah, Tk.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
from tkinter import *  # Importing everything from the Tkinter module
win = Tk()  # Initializing Tkinter and making a window

def sample():
    new_win = Toplevel()  # This creates a new window

sample()
win.mainloop()  # If this is not there, the code won't work
```